# How do I access a tasks collection on user stories using Rally .NET toolkit?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, rally

I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given
>   key was not present in the dictionary.

when iterating over user story query results and try to access story["Tasks"]

```
foreach (var story in queryStoryResults.Results)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("FormattedID: " + story["FormattedID"]);
           Console.WriteLine("Name: " + story["Name"]);
           Console.Write("Tasks: " + story["Tasks"]);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that Tasks are being fetched, along with task specific fields that you want to extract, e.g. State.
Next, a nested loop is needed inside the loop that iterates over user story results.
Here is the code example. It queries on user stories from the current iteration and prints out FormattedID and State of tasks associated with the query results:

```
namespace RESTexample_storiesFromIteration
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;
            restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@domain.com", "1984", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.43");

            //Set our Workspace and Project scopings
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1111";
            String projectRef = "/project/2222";
            bool projectScopingUp = false;
            bool projectScopingDown = true;

            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
            String nowString = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            Request iterationRequest = new Request("Iteration");
            iterationRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            iterationRequest.Project = projectRef;

            iterationRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "StartDate",
                    "EndDate",
                    "Project",
                    "State"
                };

            String iterationQueryString = "((StartDate <= \"" + nowString + "\") AND (EndDate >= \"" + nowString + "\"))";
            iterationRequest.Query = new Query(iterationQueryString);

            QueryResult queryIterationResults = restApi.Query(iterationRequest);

            var myIteration = queryIterationResults.Results.First();
            var myIterationName = myIteration["Name"];
            var myIterationProject = myIteration["Project"];
            var myIterationProjectName = myIterationProject["Name"];

            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + myIterationName);
            Console.WriteLine("Project Ref: " + myIterationProjectName);
            Console.WriteLine("State: " + myIteration["State"]);

            // Query for Stories

            Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
            storyRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            storyRequest.Project = projectRef;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeUp = projectScopingUp;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeDown = projectScopingDown;
            storyRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "ObjectID",
                    "ScheduleState",
                    "State",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "PlanEstimate",
                    "Iteration",
                    "Tasks"
                };

            storyRequest.Query = new Query("Iteration.Name", Query.Operator.Equals, myIterationName);
            QueryResult queryStoryResults = restApi.Query(storyRequest);

            foreach (var s in queryStoryResults.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----------");
                Console.WriteLine("FormattedID: " + s["FormattedID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + s["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("PlanEstimate: " + s["PlanEstimate"]);

                var tasks = s["Tasks"];

                foreach (var t in tasks)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Task: " + t["FormattedID"] + " " + t["State"]);
                 }
            }

        }
    }
}
```